# local_auth iOS (Flutter)

Tags: ios, flutter, localauthentication

Flutter local_auth didn't return platform exception when biometrics and passcode are disable for iOS.

I have a functionality where if biometrics and passcode are disable, I will use another function for authentication but it only works on Android and didn't work on iOS.

```
Future<bool> authentication() async {
    try {
      return await _localAuthentication.authenticate(
        localizedReason: Strings.localAuthReason,
        useErrorDialogs: true,
        stickyAuth: true,
      );
    } on PlatformException {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

import this code below
import 'package:local_auth/error_codes.dart' as local_auth_error;

and try this

```
 Future<bool> authentication() async {
try {
  return await _localAuthentication.authenticate(
    localizedReason: Strings.localAuthReason,
    useErrorDialogs: true,
    stickyAuth: true,
  );
} on PlatformException catch (exception) {
  if (exception.code == local_auth_error.notAvailable ||
      exception.code == local_auth_error.passcodeNotSet ||
      exception.code == local_auth_error.notEnrolled) {
    // Handle this exception here.
  }
}
```

}

Comment: I got the same results

Comment: have u add this `<key>NSFaceIDUsageDescription</key>
<string>Why is my app authenticating using face id?</string>` to your info.plist file

Comment: Yes I already had this.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).